Finding poles and zeroes for circuit driven by current source
I saw this post recently.
I had a query regarding question 1 and how FACTs can be used in the case of current source driving a circuit:


First, I set the current source to zero which is an open circuit.
Then, I look from C2 and try to find total resistance to GND, but there is no path with just resistance to ground, so what do I do?

How do I solve it, step by step? Voltage excitation circuits make sense since when a voltage source is zeroed, it creates a path to AC ground, but how to deal with current source excitation?

Why not convert the current source and resistor to a voltage source and resistor.

@Andyaka The resistor has a capacitor in series, I would need to bring that with it too? I assume you mean convert the Norton equivalent circuit into a Thevenin equivalent circuit. But a Norton circuit has a current source in parallel with a single resistor.

Yes, take the resistor and capacitor in series and make a voltage source. Then, when you zero the voltage source you get the same original circuit hence, if you can solve it with a voltage source, why can't you solve it as a current source?

You cannot ping a specific user in a post so I've edited that out.
